# Can't inspect 'content_tag', calling of any method causes an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a helper:

```
module MyHelper

  def test
    binding.pry # break point
    MyModule.test2(&content_tag)
  end

end
```

At the break point I'd like to inspect content_tag before passing it to MyModule. Nonetheless, whatever I did caused the errors:

```
content_tag
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)

(content_tag).respond_to? :call
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)

content_tag.class
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)

content_tag.is_a? Proc
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)


content_tag.lambda?
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
```

My aim is just pass it to MyModule. But I can't do this and the error is the same as the ones above. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. You call `content_tag` without arguments while this method needs at least one argument.

If you want to convert it to block and pass into `test2` method, it's possible with [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-method):

```
MyModule.test2(&method(:content_tag))
```

Comment: But I don't want to call it, I want to inspect it, does it require calling it with the arguments?

Comment: @Alex what exactly do you want to inspect? If you want to inspect its result then yes, of course it needs calling this method.

Comment: its class, if it's a lambda or a proc.

Comment: It's neither lambda nor proc, it's a method.

Comment: why doesn't it respond to class? what methods does it respond to then?

Comment: @Alex because it's a method. It's not an object - you can call `class` (and any other method) only on objects.

Comment: I see. So how can I pass it to MyModule.test2? this doesn't work causing the same error `MyModule.test2(&content_tag)`.

Comment: thanks. by the way, is `method` a method itself? it seems so.

Comment: @Alex yes, it's [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-method) method It takes symbol representing method name and returns corresponding `Method` instance.

Comment: thanks. one more question please: I tried to pass 2 of them as the arguments and it failed. I know I can't pass 2 blocks as the arguments. But does it also applicable to passing `Method`? What I tried to do was `MyModule.test2(&method(:content_tag), &method(:user_path))`

Comment: This way, you try to pass two blocks, not `Method` objects (since you use `&` operator) and that's why it fails.